# Car frequently loses its alignment over minor bumps and potholes even after getting aligned

Tags: ford, wheels, suspension, steering, alignment

I own a Dec 2019 EcoSport RHD. It has been a problem ever since I bought the car.  First there was an issue of stubborn left pull. After lot of argument, the dealer replaced the right knuckle and adjusted the sub-frame.

After that, the steering was little stiff to turn and steering was little off centre to turn but nothing difficult. I took it to another dealer and he did the wheel rotation and changed the steering rack. Steering became smooth to turn.

Since April of this year, every time I get it aligned, it's losing its alignment after hitting even minor bumps or when I drive through potholes at a very slow speed. I don't know why it happens.

Now the dealer is refusing to sort the issue anymore. What should I get it checked for? Sub-frame? Struts? Knuckle? Or control arms?

Comment: If this is under warranty don't take no for an  answer. Complain loudly to the company itself, go on social media, hound them until they take responsibility.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is no accident history here, this issue screams "worn suspension component(s)" to me.  You mentioned the right steering knuckle but there are many other components that may be the problem.

It sounds to me as if your dealer is either lazy or incompetent.  Find a better shop, preferably one that specializes in suspensions and alignment.

If there is an accident damage history, then you'll probably want to start at a good auto repair shop who can assess the damage and get the vehicle the proper sub-contractor to resolve whatever issues are there.

Comment: I will take it elsewhere & probably will find another garage, if this could be of any help, my car was never involved in accident.